# PHP Classess to handle customers with subsidiaries

Tags: php, oop, data-structures, yii2, organization

I am looking for some inspiration - how to optimally handle specific business logic in PHP / MySQL / Yii2.

I develop a production facility management system where customers may have rather complex structure, e.g. one "corporation" may have several departments and each department may have several workshops, so for instance one billing address is headquarter another one specific department while shipping addressees is some particular workshop... Then, all aggregates (totals of invoice amounts or shipped goods quantities) must be done globally or by department or by workshop...

So, this is pretty complex OOP business domain with parent-child relationships and it must be easy to be presented on screen to select where the billing and shipping should go...

If you know some good class package ready to handle this I would appreciate!

Thanks ahead!

Comment: I would suggest to use accountants software for that...

Comment: I said that - I am developing such a software. Actually, this is not for accounting, but for production management specifically. I consider your feedback pointless spamming.

Answer (score 0):

According to the text the purpose of the program is production and delivery managment. There are many softwares developed for that purpose.
As you mentioned, this is complex program, but it is complex not because of the object structre, it is complex because there are many small details to take care of... 
You should not start this joney if you not sure that existing software is not fit your needs... IMO almost any accountants software is enough...

If you decide to develop.. i would suggest the you adopt the concepts and proccesses from the accoutant world, they will directly effect the program structure.. these were evolved over the years and it would be silly to solve this kind of problem while ignoring them... So learn the concepts first

Looking for a package ?
IMO any package will not save you time, because the core functions of the program is just reading and writing from a database...
The value of any program of this type is not in it core functionality, it is in the quality and stability... most buissness preferer old accountant programs because they are stable and used many year most of the bugs where fixed... Therefore, if u use a package you sould be concerned about its quality... establishing the quality takes the most time...

Comment: Grigorij,

I would appreciate you understand the difference between "accountant software" and "production management software". Then, I would appreciate the customer need for dedicated solution - tailor-suited to their needs.

I really ask you to stop polluting this thread with your pointless remarks. Actually, I would like to decrease your SO rating because of thread spamming.